# Java generics not allowing me to add another item to the list

Tags: java, generics

I have this generic class

```
public class BinTree<T> {

    T value;

    List<BinTree<? extends T>> branch = new ArrayList<BinTree<? extends T>>();

    public BinTree(T v){ value  = v;}

    public void addBranch(BinTree<? extends T> tree){
        if(branch.size() == 2){
            System.out.println("You can only have two childs");
        }else{
            branch.add(tree);
        }
    }

    public BinTree<? extends T> getBranch(int n){ return branch.get(n);}


}
```

And its implementation here

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        BinTree<Number> firstBinTree = new BinTree<Number>(0);
        firstBinTree.addBranch(new BinTree<Integer>(5));
        firstBinTree.addBranch(new BinTree<Double>(6.5));

        Number o = firstBinTree.getBranch(0).value;
        firstBinTree.getBranch(0).addBranch(new BinTree<Integer>(6));

    }
```

But this line

```
firstBinTree.getBranch(0).addBranch(new BinTree<Integer>(6));
```

Is not allowing me to add another BinTree of Type integer. why is that? I declared in my addBranch method that it can add any type as long that is ia subclass of Type(in this case number) it would be added in the list but how come I can't ? isn't Integer a sub class of Number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not know if the

```
<? extends T>
```

in getBranch and addBranch are the same i think. So to it will be

```
<? extends ? extends T>
```

Comment: But how come on this line it worked adding branches?  firstBinTree.addBranch(new BinTree<Integer>(5));
        firstBinTree.addBranch(new BinTree<Double>(6.5));

Comment: when you are adding branches you want a <? extends T) which is <? extends Number> in that case and that case is easy to see for the compiler. But when you call getBranch , it is <_something_ extends T>

Comment: so the addbranch will be <? extends (_something_ extends T)>

Comment: so if I call getBranch it doesn't specifically know what type of branch or BinTree will it turn?

Comment: yes. it will know it extends Number. But it will not know what it is exactly.

Comment: is there anyway I can add a branch to its sub branches?

Comment: lie a bit and return <T> from getBranch

Comment: since you have limited amount of branches how about using the type parameters to define their types directly.

Comment: class<T,<L extends T>,<R extends T>>, then have method setleftBranch, setrightbranch etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is because [generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1393766).

In your example `getBranch(0)` can return `BinTree<? extends Number>` (for example `BinTree<Integer>` or `BinTree<Double>`) but compiler can't be sure about precise generic type that will be used. So from safety reasons it won't allow to use BinTree<`Integer`> in `addBranch` in case `getBranch(0)` will return ***something different*** then BinTree<`Integer`> like BinTree<`Double`>.